# K8s Pod OOM but the status shows succeeded

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

- version

k8s 1.15

- problem

I run a job with 2Gi memory limit which seems to be not enough. The status of the job shows "completed" with 1 succeeded pod;
what strange is that the pod terminated with exitcode 0, which is known as completed successfully, but infact is was killed by out of memory.

[image]

Comment: Is it one time issue, or does this happen frequently?

Comment: I have encountered this several times in my impression, no more than 10 in 5 months

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening? We also had an OOMKilled container that was started by a Job. The Job responded success so it was really hard to figure out what was going on.